# How to make a hole in fabricjs polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to make a hole inside of polygon with `fabricjs`. I can make it using normal html5 canvas with counter-clockwise as shown below, but I would prefer to make it using `fabricjs`. Does anyone know how to implement the attached image using 'fabriicjs'?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: An html5 canvas can be an image source for a `Fabric.Image`. To keep it simple, if you can draw your desire shape on html5 canvas then do it and create a Fabric.Image from the canvas.

Comment: @markE.. No.. I want create polygon programmatically with holes. i have a coordinates point  for polygon and its holes. how to make that..?

Comment: Understood! AFAIK, FabricJS does not yet support the compositing necessary to create cutouts from its polygons. My comment is a workaround and I've posted implementing details in an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one way to draw a cutout-polygon onto FabricJS:**

AFAIK, FabricJS does not yet support the compositing necessary to create cutouts from its polygons, so here's a workaround.

1. Draw the cutout polygon onto an html5 canvas. [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/mptxw1kh/)

   - Draw the polygon from your specified points.
   - Set `.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'`. This will cause all new drawings to act as an "eraser" and will cut out any existing pixels under the new drawings.
   - Draw the cutout from your specified points.
2. Use the html5 canvas as an image source for a new `Fabric.Image`.

   ```
   // Create your polygon with transparent cuts on this html5 canvas
   // Use destination-out compositing to "punch holes" in your polygon
   var html5canvas=document.getElementById('myhtml5CanvasElement');

   // then use the html5 canvas as an image source for a new Fabric.Image
   var c=new Fabric.Image(html5Canvas);
   ```

Comment: this is a good idea but some problem here.. is possible to make polygon to image from canvas. if possible please give a example. then " destination-out" make only white overlay on the object. but i want that transparent cut out.  my try [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZpdLj)

Comment: As I said in my answer, FabricJS doesn't support compositing so you must composite on a regular html5 canvas and use that canvas as an image source for your Fabric.Image. You will have a Fabric.Image containing your polygon and the 2 cutouts will be transparent. [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/poly%20with%20cutout.png) an example image. **Destination-out compositing turns pixels transparent.** So drawing your cutout paths with destination-out compositing will "punch transparent holes" in your larger polygon.

Comment: thanks @markE for your valuable time for this. i understand the concept. tanks once again